# What are the video streaming specifics: video coded parameters, web server configuration, video player?

Tags: iis-7, streaming, ffmpeg

With my server I encode videos from any format to mp4 with ffmpeg, for making play them with flowplayer on the web site. The problem is that videos buffering is not working. **Video plays once it has been fully buffered (downloaded)**.

- Should mp4 videos be encoded in any particular way for having
  streaming work?
- Or maybe the IIS7 server need extra configuration?
- I am using php for getting video files: getMedia?file=asd.mp4

I have IIS7 web server with php. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stream correctly, mp4 files need to have their metadata at the beginning of the file (so that that information is streamed first).  ffmpeg doesn't do this by default, but includes a tool, `qt-faststart`, that does the rearranging.